# JUnit test passes but won't print the pass or fail inside of try/catch

Tags: java, selenium, junit, try-catch, println

Hey I'm working with Selenium in the language of Java and I am running a simple test. My question is why does my `system.out.println` work when it's inserted into the code, but once I put it in a try/catch the JUnit test still runs and past it just doesn't print if it found the element was found or not?

Below is the working println code:

```
        WebElement zipCode = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tcom-main-nav']/ul/li[3]/button/span/span"));
    System.out.println("The zip code for the search is: " + zipCode.getText());
```

and this is the non working println code:

```
try {
    WebDriverWait waitNow = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    waitNow.until(ExpectedConditions
        .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='landing']/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[2]"))).click();

    WebElement selectedElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='landing']/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[2]"));
    System.out.println(selectedElement.getText() + " was selected");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
}
// selectedElement was not found
catch (Exception wde) {
    WebElement selectedElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='landing']/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[2]"));
    System.out.println(selectedElemen.getText() + " was not selected");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
}
```

If any of you have any answers or suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you sure this statement isn't failing? `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='landing']/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[2]"));`  It's in both your try and your catch.

Comment: See an example of exception handling in a catch block [here](https://ideone.com/HPO5uq).  It doesn't continue executing beyond the context of the block (since it is uncaught), but it will still execute the finally if it is present.

Comment: I have the xpath's in both try and catch, because I wanted to print it with the element text, but thanks that fixed it!

Thanksss!